# ipdb stops showing prompt text after carriage return

Tags: python, pdb, ipdb

Recently when setting up a breakpoint using `ipdb.set_trace(context=20)` I can see the command I'm inputing the first time, after hitting return, next time I write an instruction or command in my ipdb prompt is not showing. When I hit enter it executes it and shows it in the previous lines.

This wasn't happening until very recently. I'm using mac, with iterm, latest ipdb and pytest.

**EDIT 2022-3-29**

- I've been trying to play with the shell settings, disconnect ozsh, antigen plugins, to see it was related, but doesn't seem to affect.
- I've also tried with terminal, instead of iterm.
- Here is a recording of what I'm describing:
  [image]

**EDIT 2022-3-31**

- I've realized this only happens with one of my projects
- The prompt disappears after an exception occurs no matter which type, otherwise it always works fine.
- After the exception prompt starts failing, but sometimes it's not in the first command after
- I've written a simple python program to run with the same setup and it doesn't happen, so there's something else messing with this

**EDIT 2022-3-31 (2.0)**

- After spending some time playing with this, I discovered this was only happening in some tests, the ones decorated with freezegun

I'm using freezegun 1.2.1 and pytest 6.2.5. When I run this code if I execute print a couple times, cursor disappears. This is the most basic reproduction test I've been able to come up with.

```
import ipdb
from freezegun import freeze_time
    
    
@freeze_time("2022-3-12")
def test_prompt_ipdb():
    ipdb.set_trace()
    
test_prompt_ipdb()
```

I now believe this a bug in one of these two, most likely freezegun doing something fancy.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see what I'm typing while I type, only after I press carriage return

Comment: Having the exact same issue - also on a test that's been freeze-gunned :(

Comment: Hey! any news on this issue? I'm also having it while running freezegun (v1.2.1) with ipdb (v0.13.9) and pytest (v7.1.2)

Comment: Yes this is weird!  Only with ipdb though… pdb works fine. And only on a freezegun test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a bug in ipdb (nor in IPython for that matter, with which this reproduces as well). The problem is between freezegun and [prompt-toolkit](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit), which IPython (and consequently ipdb) rely on. I'm hoping they will accept [this PR](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/pull/481), but until then this behavior can be resolved by adding `prompt_toolkit` to the ignore-list using the `extend_ignore_list` argument, like so:

```
import ipdb
import freezegun

freezegun.configure(extend_ignore_list=['prompt_toolkit'])

@freezegun.freeze_time("2022-3-12")
def test_prompt_ipdb():
    ipdb.set_trace()

test_prompt_ipdb()
```